# Weblogic - Why Java ClassLoader does not load classes from jars mentioned in empty manifest jar

Tags: java, web-applications, classloader, weblogic12c

I have recently come across of a scenario where we would have a empty manifest jar (i.e. jar with just META-INF/MANIFEST.MF having Class-Path attribute) referring to other jar file somewhere on file system. I believe this manifest jar has been created to act like a soft link to a specific version jar so that consumer need not deal with minor version changes of implementing jar.

```
manifest.jar:-
----META-INF/
--------MANIFEST.MF

Actual version specific implementation jar (test-1.1.jar):-
----META-INF/
--------MANIFEST.MF
----test/
--------Test1.class
```

Including manifest.jar in classpath in application does not load actual implementing jar and hence I see ClassNotFoundException.
Any idea why it does not load and how can I get this jar loaded as expected?

**Update**:
I tried this with a sample executable jar and it (sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader) seems to load the class as expected. Referring just manifest.jar in Class-Path in-turn includes the actual implementing jar.
Also, I found that we do have a legacy custom class loader for the project, not sure if that causing this weird behavior.

By default, shouldn't it take care of the referencing of other jars from manifest.jar?
Is there a way to check whether this custom class loader is actually referencing jars mentioned in Class-Path?

Answer (score 1):

When using `java -jar somejar.jar`, then the classpath is set up as follows:

- Environment variable CLASSPATH is **entirely ignored**.
- The `-cp` / `-classpath` switch is **entirely ignored**.
- The `Class-Path` entry in the manifest **of the jar you specified explicitly**, i.e. `somejar.jar` is read, split on spaces, any relative paths are resolved relative to the directory the jar is in, and that is used as classpath.
- The `Class-Path` entry in any other jar file, including jar files listed in the Class-Path entry of `somejar.jar` is **entirely ignored**.
- The `Main-Class` entry in the manifest of `somejar.jar` is read, the string found there is loaded as class, and its main method is invoked. Any `Main-Class` entries in any jars you mentioned in the `Class-Path` entry is **entirely ignored**.

In other words, this proxy concept cannot really work. The jar you put in `java -jar thejar.jar` **must** have the `Main-Class` attribute *and* must list **all** the required jars to run that application in its `Class-Path` attribute.

If you use this instead: `java -cp somejar.jar:lib/dep1.jar:lib/dep2.jar:etc com.foo.Main`, then **the manifest is entirely ignored**, and thus whatever you set up in any manifest's `Class-Path` or `Main-Class` attribute is irrelevant here.

Comment: Thanks for a quick detailed response. I see you explained the possible issue while running this as a standalone executable jar. I actually meant referring to the above mentioned empty manifest.jar in application server like Weblogic where web application classloader plays a role. why would people create such a manifest.jar if its Class-Path will be ignored!

Comment: Updated the title to indicate the issue is noticed in weblogic application context not as a standalone application. Sorry, if the earlier title created any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are observing may be explained by the JAR file spec section on the [Class-Path attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#class-path-attribute).

Specifically:

> *"Currently, the URLs must be relative to the code base of the JAR file for security reasons. Thus, remote optional packages will originate from the same code base as the application."*
>
> *"Each relative URL is resolved against the code base that the containing application or library was loaded from. If the resulting URL is invalid or refers to a resource that cannot be found then it is ignored."*

So, if the `Class-Path` attribute in the `MANIFEST.MF` file for `manifest.jar` uses absolute URLs, or URLs starting with "/", or if they do not resolve relative to the location of `manifest.jar` itself, the corresponding JARs, etc won't be added to the internal classpath.  They are silently ignored.

This would happen if you just copied the `manifest.jar` into your project ...

Comment: Sorry, in my case the implementing jar (Test-1.1.jar) sits next to the manifest.jar and manifest refers it through MANIFEST.MF like:

Class-Path: Test-1.1.jar